# Turning incidental triangles to quads

Tags: mesh, topology

I'm working on a mesh with a 45° edge which left me with several triangles. I've read in several forums that having tris isn't best practice, and I should strive to always use quads.

I've come up with a solution, but I'm afraid I'm using "triangles in disguise" along the 45° edge. Is this poor practice? What topology solution should I employ to keep the original subdivisions but no triangles? I can't remove subdivisions, but I can add new edge loops, so this is what I came up with:

[image]

Comment: That depends on the purpose of the mesh.. How will it be used? Will it be subsurfed? Where are the visible parts? (those which need most details) Do you really need all those loopcuts going to the bottom and side? Probably you can leave it as is.. But if using Subsurf most likely can't. Subdividing in order to get quad which has form of tri indeed doesn't seem to have any use.

Comment: In case anyone runs into similar topology issues in the future, I found this YT video very helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGL6QpVRyXk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Final:

[image: Final]

### Overview:

This is the cleanest quad topology I can think of.

I don't know if this is the proper way, but for me it works always the best. Try not to think about quad topology but about **Edge Loops** and how can you use them along the mesh. If you will work that way, quads will come naturally after some time.

Here you have example with **Edge Loop** that will allow to control sharpness of the **Edge** itself combined with **Subsurf Modifier**.